# Show a specific value in last in SSRS

Tags: sql, reporting-services

[image]

Here, I want the "other brands" should be in the last row in that group always.

I use the below case to show the Brand column

```
CASE 
    WHEN INFO.OTHERID = 1 THEN INFO.BRAND 
    WHEN INFO.OTHERID = 0 THEN 'Other Brands'
    ELSE '-' 
END AS BRANDS
```

Comment: Use ORDER BY to sort the result-set rows.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need two sort expressions inside your group.

The first expression will be something like

```
=IIF(Fields.BRANDS.Value = 'Other Brands', 1, 0)
```

and the second sort expression will be

```
=Fields!BRANDS.Value
```

This will first sort by whether or not it's your 'Other Brands' line, making sure this line appears last, then it will sort the remaining lines by the actual field value.